# ClosedXML.Report Multiple Pivot Tables in multiple Worksheets of same Workbook

Tags: closedxml.report

I am trying to generate one pivot table per worksheet in the same workbook.
My Data has the following structure,
`List<string,List<mydata>>` where each string would represent a worksheet in the workbook, and the list  would be the data i want to make a pivot table from.

My data Class is like this:

```
public class mydata{
 public string Type_Mark { get; set; }
 public string Category { get; set; }
 public double Length { get; set; }
 public string System_Classification { get; set; }
}
```

I am totally confused to as how do i tell closedXML.Report what data go to what pivot table and on which worksheet.
I am also confused about how to set the columns that i want from the my data to go into each pivot, since not all pivot tables would use the same fields.

can someone provide the sequence i need to follow to achieve that?  What goes in the Excel File Template and what goes in the code.  Do i need to create ranges in the template?

thanks,